# Update Product prices after adding to cart

Tags: magento2, event-observer, addtocart

I am trying to update product prices after adding to cart but the change on prices don't apply on it. I have created an event on `checkout_cart_product_add_after` while on observer I have written code like this :

```
class Cart implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {


        $item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');
switch ($item->getQty()) {
                    case '2':
                        $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($newarray[0]);
                        $item->setCustomPrice($newarray[0]);
                        $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
                        break;
                   case '3':
                        $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($newarray[1]);
                        $item->setCustomPrice($newarray[1]);
                        $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
                        break; 
                 case '4':
                        $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($newarray[2]);
                        $item->setCustomPrice($newarray[2]);
                        $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
                        break;
                case '5':
                        $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($newarray[3]);
                        $item->setCustomPrice($newarray[3]);
                        $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
                        break;

                }


    }
}
```

`$newarray` array have different prices `( $newarray[0] => 29.5,$newarray[1]=>29.00  etc)`, at the last line when I show `$item->getOriginalCustomPrice();` it shows new price but on the cart, the old prices are shown. Thanks

Comment: check with this url  - https://webkul.com/blog/magento2-set-custom-price-of-product/

Comment: @AnasMansuri I think both codes are the same.

Comment: @Mahmood Rehman, have sure that this observer is hit for your add to cart. Code seems ok

Comment: @AmitBera Yes when I print something with exit it stops and shows the message on the console. It means code is working fine after adding to cart but prices didn't get updated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the item and add a new one with the updated price :

```
//get the product from the observer 
$product = $observer->getEvent()->getData('product');

//get the item just added
$item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');

//define the new price
$yourNewPrice = 100;

//get the current store
$storeId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();

//get the quote
$quote = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote();

//create a new item
$quoteItemNewPrice = $this->objectManager->create('Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item');


//set data to this new item
$quoteItemNewPrice->setQuote($quote); //set quote
$quoteItemNewPrice->setStoreId($storeId); //set store id
$quoteItemNewPrice->setProduct($product); //set the product
$quoteItemNewPrice->setQty($item->getQty());  //set the quantity from the old item
$quoteItemNewPrice->setPrice($yourNewPrice); //set the price
$quoteItemNewPrice->setOriginalCustomPrice($yourNewPrice);

//remove the current item
$item->delete();

//add the new item to the quote and save it
$quote->addItem($quoteItemNewPrice);
$quote->save();
```

Note: you must inject some missing classes such as the _checkoutSession

Comment: No luck with your code. Same original prices are added to cart.

Comment: I may have made a mistake, try to first save the quote and then remove the old item ($item->delete())